# UseSplitVerifier argument for command line Gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I wish to use the JVM argument -XX:-UseSplitVerifier in Gradle, via the command line.

In Android Studio, this can be done in the GUI by editing the Run/Debug Configuration and adding `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the "VM options" box. If I want to run `gradlew :myProject:test` from the command line, however, it doesn't seem to use Android Studio's run config, and thus the argument `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` seems to not be set.

I tried stuff along the lines of `gradlew -D-XX:-UseSplitVerifier :myProject:test` but nothing I tried seems to add this JVM argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running Gradle from the command line, you have to specify JVM options via either the `JAVA_OPTS` or `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variables. See the [Gradle documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/installation.html#N10162) for more info.